# passing parameter value to a function in an external script file in actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I would like to know how to pass a parameter to a function which is in an external actionscript file linked to a button. In the above code when I click on the button I get the following error. I think there is a problem in the way I am passing values to the function. Help please.

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Node(). Expected 1, got 0.
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()




package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;

    public class Node extends SimpleButton
    {
          public var left:Node;      // left child
          public var right:Node;    // right child
          public var value:int = int.MAX_VALUE;   // value in node
          public var test:int;

          public function Node(c:int):void
            {
                value = c;
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AddClick);
            }
            public function AddClick(e:Event):void
            {

                Node(25);
                trace(value);
            }

    }//class

}//package
```

Comment: If this error happens when you click the button, what code is run with that click?

Comment: You might need to first get a better understanding of the language by following some tutorials in order to properly express what you want to do. As it is, the code that you have as an example makes no sense to what you describe in your comment to Smolniy, and your question becomes more about how to use the language, that how to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you create and object in library and write class for that object, you can instantiate that object in 2 ways:

1. Dragging instance from library. You can't pass parameters to constructor function.
2. Creating instance by `new` command. You can pass parameters to constructor function.

If you want instantiate object with both methods, you need set default values for constructor parameters (for method 1):

`public function Node(c:int=0)`

I suppose, you create object with method 1. Your error occurs on app start, not on button press.

By the way, in your code you call constructor function in strange manner :)
`Node(25);` - wrong, you need `var foo:Node = new Node(25);`

And if you just want change value to 25, write

```
public function AddClick(e:Event):void
      {

                value = 25;
                trace(value);
      }
```

All functions and values in class Node  'lives' on one scope and accessible directly.

Comment: I typed var foo:Node = new Node(25); in the AddClick event. But I still get the same error. Maybe I am doing it wrong. Excuse my lack of knowledge regarding actionscript since I am new to this language. What I need to get done is I have a text field where I get a number as a user input and I want to pass that number as a parameter to Node function in the AddClick event. :)